# No hay movimiento de discos Torres de Hanói RISC-V

Tags: ensamblador

Hola estoy haciendo un programa de Torres de Hanoi en RISC-V, lo estoy compilando en el programa de Ripes. A la hora de ver el Memory view, y dirigirme a ver el .data no realiza los movimientos de los discos, aunque si inicializa correctamente estos mismos y las torres.

La verdad ya no se que más ser, y no soy muy conocedor del tema, es muy inestable el programa y cuando cambio cualquier cosa, deja de servir, alguien que me pueda ayudar :(?

Este es mi código al momento:

```
.data
memPtr:
.text

addi s1 zero 0     # Pointer to the source tower
addi s2 zero 0     # Pointer to the auxiliary tower
addi s3 zero 0     # Pointer to the destination tower

addi s9 zero 0     # Disk counter

addi a1 zero 3     # Number of elements
addi a0 zero 3     # Disk counter (initialized to the number of disks)
addi s5 zero 1     # 1 for comparisons
addi t0 zero 4

jal ra main
jal ra hanoi
jal ra end

main:
    lui s1 %hi(memPtr)
    addi s1 s1 %lo(memPtr)
    mul s2 a1 t0
    add s2 s1 s2
    mul s3 a1 t0
    add s3 s2 s3
    add s11 zero s1

fill:
    sw a0 0(s1)
    addi a0 a0 -1
    addi s1 s1 4
    addi a3 a3 1
    bnez a0 fill    # Use bnez instead of blt to handle the zero case
    addi s1 s1 -4
    add s1 zero s11
    jalr zero ra 0
```

hanoi:
addi sp sp -20
sw a3 0(sp)     # Store the number of disks
sw s1 4(sp)     # Store the source tower pointer
sw s2 8(sp)     # Store the auxiliary tower pointer
sw s3 12(sp)    # Store the destination tower pointer
sw ra 16(sp)    # Store the return address

```
bnez a3 forLoop   # Check if a3 (number of disks) is not zero
jal ra end
```

forLoop:
addi a3 a3 -1
add t0 zero s1
add s1 zero s2
add s2 zero s3
add s3 zero t0
jal ra hanoi
addi a3 a3 1

empty:
lw s9 0(s3)
addi s3 s3 4
bnez s9 empty   # Use bnez to check for non-empty space
addi s3 s3 -4
sw a3 0(s3)
add s3 zero t6

```
addi a3 a3 -1
add t0 zero s1
add s1 zero s3
add s3 zero s2
add s2 zero t0
jal ra hanoi
addi a3 a3 1

lw a3 0(sp)
lw s1 4(sp)
lw s2 8(sp)
lw s3 12(sp)
lw ra 16(sp)
addi sp sp 20
jalr zero ra 0
```

end:
add s10 zero zero